# Why does VS2015's intellisense keep leaving the opening bracket after "else"?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, formatting, intellisense, curly-brackets

This is what makes me mad:

[image]

See, I press "Format Document" and everything sweetly suits to where it belongs, but after I switched from VS2013 to VS2015, this **opening bracket** after `else` never goes to the next line until I manually insert a carriare return between them!

Now, I see what you are thinking, "go to the tools, options, text editor, C#, etc etc", but look at this:

[image]

Every checkbox is checked and yet even the preview mocks me with that curly brace.

How do I make this like it was in VS2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, they fixed it. Which means it was a bug.